# filter and sort columns with groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this df:

```
   Date                  Plate     Route     Speed   VehiceType
0  2020-11-03 13:54:00   0660182   Route 66   32      Wagon
1  2020-11-03 13:25:03   939CH003  Route 35   24      Truck
2  2020-11-03 09:27:11   WH3457    Route 02   41      Bus
```

and so on. I need time differences between same plate vehicles, which I easily obtain as:

```
df.groupby('Plate').Date.diff( )
```

then, I sort (otherwise I would have differences between different dates/plates, which I dont need) and group like this:

```
df2 = df.sort_values(by=['Plate', 'Date']).groupby('Plate').Date.diff().dt.total_seconds().reset_index()
```

i end up with a df (after renaming one column) like this:

```
      index   Difference (s)
0     34517   NaN 
1     377539  33.0
2     119714  34.0
3     300900  765.0
```

that's not what I need ("index" column is supposed to be that of plates'). What I want is something like:

```
    Plate   Difference
0   WH3457  54.0
1   9W432T  24.0
2   947CH05 33.0
```

so that this df can be merged in the original one (left_on and right_on) by plate number for some filters. Pandas says merge cant be done because "index" column is just numbers, while plate column is clearly a string (I miss plate objects somehow when sorting).
So, how can I obtain this plate/difference df? (sort by plate and date is a must, otherwise differences makes no sense).
I've been struggling with this and cant get it. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

This is a bigger chunk of original df (sorry about alignment and vehicle type in spanish):

```
    Date                        Plate       Route       Latitude    Longitud    Speed   VehicleType
0   2020-11-17 13:54:00+00:00   0660182     RUTA 66     19.333958   -99.199240  10  AUTOBUS LARGO (MAYOR A 10 M DE LONGITUD)
1   2020-11-17 13:54:00+00:00   939CH001M   RUTA 51     19.256760   -98.955510  22  AUTOBUS LARGO (MAYOR A 10 M DE LONGITUD)
2   2020-11-17 13:54:00+00:00   596NZ008M   RUTA 102    19.448385   -98.952400  0   VAGONETA
3   2020-11-17 13:54:00+00:00   0790024     RUTA 79     19.429462   -99.150820  0   MICROBUS (MENOR A 7.5 M DE LONGITUD)
4   2020-11-17 13:54:01+00:00   947CH045M   RUTA 50     19.282007   -99.009000  28  MICROBUS (MENOR A 7.5 M DE LONGITUD)
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
1279721     2020-11-18 05:59:57+00:00   0120414     RUTA 12     19.357872   -99.077920  0   MICROBUS (MENOR A 7.5 M DE LONGITUD)
1279722     2020-11-18 05:59:58+00:00   1090016     CETRAM XOCHIMILCO 200826    19.295107   -99.102936  0   MICROBUS (MENOR A 7.5 M DE LONGITUD)
1279723     2020-11-18 05:59:59+00:00   0350144     RUTA 35     19.297995   -99.061150  0   VAGONETA
1279724     2020-11-18 05:59:59+00:00   006908      RUTA 106    19.490650   -99.174640  0   AUTOBUS CORTO (ENTRE 7.5 Y 10 M DE LONGITUD)
1279725     2020-11-18 05:59:59+00:00   0340071     RUTA 34     19.324417   -99.165500  1   MICROBUS (MENOR A 7.5 M DE LONGITUD)
```

Comment: please try posting the code to create an appropriate dataframe, so we can test any potential answers, yours has only 3 rows!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you desire to place your calculation (diff in seconds) back to the original dataframe, you can use pandas [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) instead:

```
df['diff_in_sec'] = df.groupby('Plate').Date.transform(lambda x: x.diff().dt.total_seconds())
```

Furthermore, since your `apply` function doesn't perform any **aggregation**, `df2` has the same original row shape as `df` so that `index` can be used to map the values back to `df` like this:

```py
df2 = df.sort_values(by=['Plate', 'Date']).groupby('Plate').Date.diff().dt.total_seconds()
# this
df.loc[df2.index, 'diff_in_sec'] = df2
# or this
df2.name = 'diff_in_sec'
df.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: I have a problem: it marks an error, saying: AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Date'

Comment: Don't you have a column named 'Date' (exactly like this)?

Comment: Yes I have, that was my error, sorry about that (i got confused between spanish/english column names), you answer works perfectly. Big thank you.